# Is an anchor link registered as duplicate content by Google?

Tags: seo, url, duplicate-content, links

I have a store where fairly important content is now viewed by all visitors (only 66% according to mouseflow) as users have to scroll a bit to see it, which not all do.

I don't wish to move the content up at this time, but wanted to add an anchor to all source links that would skip the header of the eshop and go directly to the content. This would provide 100% views of what I want.

But will Google register anchor links as duplicate content of non-anchor links?  Would I lose PageRank from this?

`/food.html` AND `/food.html#bread` - duplicate content or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anchor text and/or URLs used in links is not a factor in determining duplicate content. The actual content of the page (text, etc) is what can trigger duplicate content issues. But linking to the same URL multiple times, with or without fragment identifiers, will not cause duplicate content issues.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm using some ajax product filters which change the url and webmaster tools flagged is as duplicated content.

Comment: That' something different. If different URLs is pulling up the same content, that is duplicate content and a problem. But that's not what you described in your question.

Comment: @JohnConde is correct. Google differentiates (unless instructed not to in the webmastertools) when pages have querystring parameters, like `?id=12`, but not hashtags, so it considers it the same page